# Converting a pdf to jpeg using Rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rmagick, temporary-files, imagelist

I am trying to convert a pdf to a jpeg image using Rmagick. I am running into some trouble with the following code:

```
pdf_link = "https://staging.shurpa.com/deliveries/BtrPsIxl/label.pdf"

file = Tempfile.new(['order', '.jpeg'])
    p pdf_link
    p file.path 
    im = ImageList.new(pdf_link)
    puts "SUPP"
    im.write(file.path.to_s)
```

I recieve this error:

```
"https://staging.shurpa.com/deliveries/BtrPsIxl/label.pdf"
"/var/folders/qm/yk_w5d9545j_6wqk6100dhjm0000gq/T/order20170706-43294-
15myct1.png"

Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open file `/var/folders/qm/yk_w5d9545j_6wqk6100dhjm0000gq/T/magick-43294MCNyzIu4Oenn': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544from/Users/timnaughton/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:1616:in `read'
```

However the code works perfectly fine when I feed it this pdf_string:

```
"https://shippo-delivery-east.s3.amazonaws.com/b2a3e1cd070748cd80b492aa421832a3.pdf?Signature=nf6woycGiOydPI8eSnLcq3r0tEc%3D&Expires=1530816480&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGLCC5MYLLWIG42A"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to have been an issue with the service that was providing the pdf to me. The pdf was recently changed to a secure state and I needed to utilize access keys. This resulted in rmagick not being able to access the image file and returning the stated error.